# How to edit specific elements in XML file using HXT?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

In short, here is what I want to accomplish:

`"foo.xml"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz>
      <a>foo</a>
      <a>bar</a>
      <a>baz</a>
    </baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

expected result (contents of `"bar.xml"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz>
      <a>foo!</a>
      <a>bar!</a>
      <a>baz!</a>
    </baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

...my attempt to approach the problem:

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad

import Control.Arrow.ArrowTree
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main :: IO ()
main = void . runX $ readDocument [] "foo.xml" >>>
       applic >>> writeDocument [withIndent yes] "bar.xml"

applic :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
applic = getChildren >>> hasName "foo"
--       ^^ because of extra root node (?)
         /> hasName "bar" /> hasName "baz" /> hasName "a" >>> changeText excl

excl :: String -> String
excl = (++ "!")
```

**Question:** How to directly edit just selected elements without changing/removing their root elements? Also note that this program doesn't create `"bar.xml"` file, so something is definitely wrong. Tracing shows that after applying `applic` arrow, the document consists of three `a` elements (`"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"`; without exclamation points).

Comment: @AJFarmar, I guess it should be possible to do without lens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't pretend to be good at HXT, I haven't used it much, but I've gotten what you want to do to work through some experimentation.  If someone has more experience with HXT feel free to offer a better solution.

I found through skimming over the [HXT wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/HXT#Decorating_external_references_of_an_HTML_document) the `process*` functions, like `processTopDown` and `processChildren`, along with several others.  These seem to be what actually allows change to happen.  Now, I'm assuming that your actual use case is more complex, you may only want to select elements at a certain level.  The pattern I stumbled upon was to use `processChildren` along with the HXT version of `when`, not the `Control.Monad` one since they are not the same.  Basically, my first implementation was

```hs
applic
    = processChildren
    $ flip when (isElem >>> hasName "foo")
        $ processChildren
        $ flip when (isElem >>> hasName "bar")
            $ processChildren
            $ flip when (isElem >>> hasName "baz")
                $ processChildren
                $ flip when (isElem >>> hasName "a")
                    $ processChildren
                $ flip when isText
                    $ changeText excl
```

And this is really quite ugly to me, there's just way too much repetition.  So I abstracted this out to something that is much more readable:

```hs
-- Fixity is important here, must be right-associative.
infixr 5 />/
(/>/) :: ArrowXml a => String -> a XmlTree XmlTree -> a XmlTree XmlTree
name />/ action
    = processChildren
    $ action `when` (isElem >>> hasName name)

applic = "foo" />/ "bar" />/ "baz" />/ "a" />/
    processChildren (
        changeText excl `when` isText
    )
```

All these calls to `processChildren` might be redundant, particularly if you're just drilling down into the structure, but it definitely works and it won't modify other `a` elements in different parts of the file.

Comment: It works! However I can't believe that users of HXT *have to invent new primitives* in order to work through such simple cases. I'll wait, maybe someone can propose idiomatic (for HXT) solution. Thank you.

Comment: On the other hand, it's really good that `processChildren` is not recursive (like `deep`), so maybe this is really way to go. I think I'm gonna accept the answer. (This is the question that entire `#haskell` channel couldn't answer (or was not willing to...)).

Comment: @Mark This kind of question that requires time and/or specialised knowledge and doesn't benefit too much from casual discussion is much better suited for the StackOverflow format than IRC, so read too much into that. :)

Comment: @Mark there was the `processTopDown` function which would have allowed this to be implemented as ```processTopDown (changeText excl `when` isText)```, but it would have affected every text node in the tree.  The nesting is needed because you're pretty much having to recreate each layer of the tree (I think?) as you go.  There is almost certainly a better way to do it, I just don't have the domain specific knowledge to know what that solution is.